# systemd "wants" directory for a custom target; does not seem to work as expected

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I create a "target" in /etc/systemd/system that is very simple

sp-example.target

```
[Unit]
Description=SP Example Target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I then create a directory called /etc/systemd/system/sp-example.target.wants.  In this directory, I put a link to my service and restart the system. It doesn't start the service, but it does start the target. I move the link from this sp-example.target.wants directory into multi-user.target.wants and reboot and the service starts.

Comment: This folder /etc/systemd/system/sp-example.target.wants is actually a link to another disk. It seems that systemd mounts the disks later and may already be determining this folder is empty (bad link). Maybe I need a way to trigger systemd to rescan for the wants folder.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "wants" directories cannot be on another disk that is not yet mounted unless systemd is reloaded as follows after the disk is mounted.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart <service>
```

Putting this in a later rc5.d script causes the problem to be solved.

Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/700862/do-systemd-unit-files-have-to-be-reloaded-when-modified